# Problems with ServiceStack Authentication when deployed to IIS 7

Tags: authentication, iis-7, servicestack

I am having problems getting authentication to work when deploying to my IIS 7 production web server. I am using the in memory authentication and everything works perfectly when I run locally from Visual Studio. However when I try to connect to the production web server, from a WPF application using the ServiceStack client, I am getting different errors including:

- "Not Found"
- "Unauthorised"
- "{"Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length"}"

I have tried numerous configurations of authentication in IIS including enabling/disabling Forms Authentication, Windows Authentication and Basic Authentication, all to no avail.

- I can sometimes connect using the CodeInChaos.com REST client.
- The password and username are definitely correct.

`global.asax`:

```cs
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    RegisterPlugins();
    RegisterValidators(container);
    RegisterCaches(container);
    RegisterSessionFactories(container);
    RegisterRepositories(container);
    RegisterUsers(container);
}

private void RegisterPlugins()
{
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider()}));
}        

private void RegisterUsers(Funq.Container container)
{
    var userRepository = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
    container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepository);

    string hash;
    string salt;

    new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString("xxxxxxxx", out hash, out salt);
    userRepository.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
    {
        Id = 1,
        DisplayName = "xxx xxxxxx",
        Email = "xxxx@xxxxx.com",
        UserName = ""xxxxxxxx,
        FirstName = "xxxx",
        LastName = "xxxx",
        PasswordHash = hash,
        Salt = salt,
        Roles = new List<string> { RoleNames.Admin },
    }, "xxxxxxxx");
}
```

My client:

```cs
public UserEntity GetUserFromDomainUsername(string domainUsername)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new StormJsonServiceClient(WebServiceUrl){UserName = "xxxxxxx", Password = "xxxxxxxx"})
        {
            var response = client.Send(new UserFromDomainUsernameQuery { DomainUsername = domainUsername });
            return response.User;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        var ex = exception as WebServiceException;
        if (ex != null)
        {
            throw new VqsWebServiceException(GetWebServiceErrorMessage(ex));
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `web.config`. Ensure you enable `DebugMode = true` in your `AppHost` config so you can get useful stack traces. IIS authentication is not related to ServiceStack authentication, turn it off if you don't need it. You said you are getting 3 different errors, presumably you made 3 different requests and not the same request 3 times? You would be best to deploy a simple application, i.e. one without authentication to test that you have set your IIS configuration up correctly as this is your first deployment, if that worked, enabled authentication.

Comment: Hi Scott - thank you. Believe it or not, that was the answer... Just turn off all authentication in IIS apart from Anonymous and it all worked. Thank you very much for the guidance. Simon

Comment: That's great. I have added an answer to this effect, so you can close the question, and so others can easily identify what helped. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS authentication is not related to ServiceStack authentication, turn it off if you don't need it.

If you have IIS authentication enabled it would run effectively on top of your ServiceStack application. So it would run before all requests to your ServiceStack service and you would end up having to satisfy this security criteria first. If this passed your request would then go through to the ServiceStack application.

Most people implementing authentication in ServiceStack will not require IIS to also implement authentication.